# Why is my object not destroyed when the HP is reduced?

Tags: unity, c#

I tried to write a script that declares an object to have hp 90 initially and every time you click on the object, it turns red and will reduce the hp by 10. When the hp is lower than 10, it should destroy the object.

But when I click my object 10 times, it still is not destroyed. How can I fix this code?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        var hp = 90;
        _ = hp - 10;

        if(hp < 10)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you click, you reset back your hp to 90. Consider setting a current hp var at the start and just reduce it every click.

```
public int maxHp = 90;
private int currentHp;

void Start()
{
    currentHp = maxHp
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    currentHp -= 10;
    if(currentHp < 10)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

You can set your max hp via the editor or just set it directly.